# Simple discrete math question

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, interpolation

It's been a long time since I took discrete math in college and I was never good at it, so I'm asking for some help with something I need to populate a chart in C#.

X = 2, the output for 2 is 0, and with each iteration the input increases by 3 and the output increases by 1.

```
input | output
______|_______
  2   |   0
______|_______
  5   |   1
______|_______
  8   |   2
```

and so on. I tried finding a value for `a` for `input % a = output` but didn't come up with anything. I feel like this is a simple problem but it just isn't my thing. Is there a function that given an input will give me the proper output? I need this to work, like if I put in 23 I need to get 7 without knowing that 20 was 6.

Comment: The relationship is linear.

Comment: I asked a co-worker also and he was like "why not just divide by 3 with no remainder" and I was just like ...oh.

Comment: Either do what your coworker said, or $y(x) = \frac{x-2}3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{3}$$ and plug input for $x$, then $f(x)$ will return output.

Comment: This works, thank you!